# Error file_get_contents on emailOutputTo Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to develop an application in laravel 5.1 and i need to do some schedule tasks. I have this code (only for tests, of course :) )

```
    $schedule->command('inspire')
    ->dailyAt('04:00')
    ->sendOutputTo(storage_path('app/logs/logs.txt'))
    ->emailOutputTo('test@test.com');
```

However, when i execute the command php artisan schedule:run to test if i receive the email and the file logs.txt is created, the system gives me an error:

> [ErrorException] file_get_contents('/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/laravelApp/storage/app/logs/logs.txt '): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This error is relate with emailOutputTo, because if i remove this part of code, i don't have any error and the file logs.txt is created.
The OS of my server is ubuntu 14.04.

Any help will be apreciated! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting that error because the `emailOutputTo()` method can't find the file

> [ErrorException]
>
> file_get_contents('/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/laravelApp/storage/app/logs/logs.txt '):
>
> failed to open stream: **No such file or directory**

If you look at the [Laravel source for the method `emailOutputTo()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L737) you have the following:

```
public function emailOutputTo($addresses, $onlyIfOutputExists = false)
{
    if (is_null($this->output) || $this->output == $this->getDefaultOutput()) {
        throw new LogicException('Must direct output to a file in order to e-mail results.');
    }

    $addresses = is_array($addresses) ? $addresses : func_get_args();

    return $this->then(function (Mailer $mailer) use ($addresses, $onlyIfOutputExists) {
        $this->emailOutput($mailer, $addresses, $onlyIfOutputExists);
    });
}
```

Which calls:

[`emailOutput()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L771) which does the following:

```
protected function emailOutput(Mailer $mailer, $addresses, $onlyIfOutputExists = false)
{
    $text = file_get_contents($this->output);

    if ($onlyIfOutputExists && empty($text)) {
        return;
    }

    $mailer->raw($text, function ($m) use ($addresses) {
        $m->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            $m->to($address);
        }
    });
}
```

I am guessing that in `emailOutput()` the first line is causing the issue:

```
$text = file_get_contents($this->output);
```

If your file is getting created then I'm a bit stumped as to why it's then throwing this error to be honest, but either way it's not picking it up so it may be something to do with the path.

On the other hand a quick google of `failed to open stream: No such file or directory "emailOutputTo"` yields the following link: [Bug with task scheduling when using emailOutputTo()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11517) which doesn't clearly look to me like it's resolved (although it is closed), unless I'm missing something. Perhaps try upgrading to the latest version of Laravel to see if that fixes the issue for you, if you can.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply haakym. However i have the same error with this code... :/
The sendOutputTo method is working fine and the file 'logs.txt' is created. i think the error is related with emailOutputTo method.

Comment: You're welcome. Oh my bad, sorry! I'll update my answer with some suggestions!

Comment: Inded @haakym it is a little strange because the file is created and i can see and edit the file....
I already see this link https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11517 and i have the same opinion than you, for me it isn't resolved... :/
Actually i can't update Laravel (maybe in a near furture). Maybe it is better to create a new artisan command to send an email with the logs file and call it using the method after. (It isn't the best approach but it could work)

Comment: Ah okay. Yes, that's probably the best approach til the issue is resolved. All the best with your solution.